# Xcode compilation target settings

Tags: ios, xcode

How many places in Xcode do we have to change a setting if we want to compile & link an app against a particular iOS version? So far, I've found three places that need to be changed:

1. [Project] / Info / iOS Deployment Target
2. [Target] / iOS Application Target / Deployment Target
3. Interface Builder Document / Document Versioning / Deployment

E.g., I've been developing against SDK 6.1, but will probably switch to 6.0 to support more users.

Comment: Search for "building for older iOS version" and you might find this is simpler than you're thinking it is. Good luck.

Comment: The Deployment Target is not used to specify what version to compile and link with. That is the job of the Base SDK setting. The Deployment Target only specifies how far back you wish to support.